# Ordering items by sizename when it's not alphabetically logic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app, the admin may add sizes to his products in this order.

- `Variant.create(size_name: "L")`
- `Variant.create(size_name: "S")`
- `Variant.create(size_name: "XXL")`
- `Variant.create(size_name: "XL")`

Sizes could also be (30,24, 33, 31, 29)

In my product view, the select tag display in the order it has been created. 
I would like to sort from the smallest size to the biggest (S, M, L ...). 
With the numerically sizes,I can order from the smallest to the biggest it's Okay

How I am supped to make sure that both sizes (the numerically and the alphabetically) could be sorted from the smallest to the biggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this, but at the core of any solution you need to *define the order manually* (or use a third party library which has already written this manual ordering for you?).

For example, you could somewhere define e.g.

```
SIZE_NAMES = %w[XS S M L XL XXL]
```

and then elsewhere in the code, use something like:

```
variants.sort_by { |variant| SIZE_NAMES.index(variant.size) }
```

For a more "advanced" solution, you could instead consider defining each size as a **custom object** rather than a regular `String`. Take a look at the [`Comparable` module](https://apidock.com/ruby/Comparable), and the `<=>` ("spaceship") operator.

By utilising this, you could potentially implement it in such a way that e.g. `variants.sort` will automatically compare variants by their "converted" size, and order them as you expect.

Comment: You could also create a Hash that maps each size to an integer e.g. `SIZE_ORDER = SIZE_NAMES.each_with_index.to_h` and then `variants.sort_by(&SIZE_ORDER)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to do sorting on db side then you have two options:

1. Predefined sort like so:

   ```
   Variant.order(
    "CASE size_name
       WHEN 'S' THEN 1
       WHEN 'L' THEN 2
       WHEN 'XL' THEN 3
       WHEN 'XXL' THEN 4
       ELSE 10
     END, size, id"
   )
   ```

   You might want to move it to scope so in case you need to add another `size_name` there is only one place to change
2. With [active record enums](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

   ```
   enum size_name: { s: 0, l: 1, xl: 2, xxl: 3 }
   ```

   That way, you can still assign the field by the string/symbol, but the underlying data will actually be an integer, so you can just use `order(:size_name, :size)` to sort by `size_name` and `size`.

   Also this way you can add index to speed up ordering